# React native ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps not working Android

Tags: android, react-native

I have the following code, which works on my iOS app and keeps the keyboard open when clicking anywhere on the screen, but on Android it still closes the keyboard, any ideas?

```
return (
            <ScrollView
                style={ styles.flex }
                automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={ false }
                keyboardShouldPersistTaps={ true }
                contentInset={{ 'bottom':20 }}
                keyboardDismissMode='on-drag'
                >
                <View>...</View>
            </ScrollView>
        );
```

Comment: It may be, because your touches are detected as Drag and you have the keyboardDismissMode enabled to `on-drag`. If not, would it be possible for you to provide a https://rnplay.org/ snippet?

Comment: I've tried to remove that but it hasn't made a difference. It's odd that it's only a problem on the Android emulator. I don't think I could break it down to put on replay I'm afraid it's a big project.

Comment: Maybe are you using `FlatList` inside the `View` ?

Answer (score 10):

if your ScrollView/FlatList is inside another ScrollView/Flatlist you have to set keyboardShouldPersistTaps to parent ScrollView/Flatlist as well as all nested ones

Comment: Tested and confirming, keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled" need to be on specific ScrollView and its parents. Leaving it on top level ScrollView was not enough.

Comment: This was my issue. I was inside a `ScrollView` inside a  `<Modal />` component that was inside a parent `FlatList` once I added to the parent `FlatList` all was good. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I am expecting above answers would have fixed your problem, here is the [doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview)

Just a side note, you should provide  `keyboardShouldPersistTaps` to the first ScrollView on the screen.

Comment: Brilliant man ❤️

Answer (score 3):

Can you please try this. keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"

Answer (score 3):

Value `true` was deprecated for this option, use `always` instead:

```
keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"
```

[Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#keyboardshouldpersisttaps)

Answer (score 2):

Actually using `keyboardShouldPersistTaps` on the parent `ScrollView` **And** also the `ScrollView` that was containing my touchable content, solved my problem.

**Example:**

```
<ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps={"always"}>
  <Text> Hello World </Text>
  <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps={"always"}>
      // Here my touchable contents are being rendered and
      // I need to keep keyboard open when I tap on each of them
      {myTags.map((el,ind)=>{ return(...)}
  </ScrollView>
  <Text> The bottom content of my tags </Text>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not proper syntax you should use

keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled' or the other values is 'always'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).